# Execution of infinite loop in c exe vs c# exe

Tags: windows, exe

I created a c program which has infinite loop.It runs fine.I also created c# program which has infinite loop.While the form ran,latter program process **stopped responding**.Why does both behaves differently?
Below are the codes

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i>=10;i++){
        printf("%d",i);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

c# program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{




public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i=10;
        while (i > 1)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

My question is how infinite loops work in these two programs?

Comment: Your C program also stops responding.  You can bang on the keyboard and mouse button and the program just completely ignores that.  You think it is normal for the C program but not normal for the GUI program.  It is just normal in both cases, you just care more about the GUI being unresponsive because you are used to them *not* doing this.  Don't write infinite loops on the UI thread.

Comment: @HansPassant:c program was running in the sense it was continuosly processing and giving output..and also i could stop it like any normal program

Comment: Because it was running in a console window. You were just closing the console window, which implicitly terminated the application. If you ran the C# program in a virtual machine, you'd get the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your C# program is in a form. Windows expects the form to be able to process events (e.g. telling it to close) but it can't because it's in the infinite loop.

If the infinite loop was in its own thread, or you wrote a C# console application instead of a form-based one, I think it would behave more like your C.